# Jquery using .parent() multiply 2data with 2 body

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

How can I multiply text box with 2 tbody by using to.parent().find() I try to use it but It's not working.
in my html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"  name="quantity_box[0]" class="form-control a" /></td>
      <td><input type="text"  name="unit_price[]" class="form-control b" /> </td>
      <td>display in <input type="text" name="price[] "  class="form-control price" autofocus=" " /> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="row1">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"  name="quantity_box[0]" class="form-control a" /></td>
      <td><input type="text"  name="unit_price[]" class="form-control b" /> </td>
      <td>display in <input type="text" name="price[] "  class="form-control price" autofocus=" " /> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My JS

```
$('.a,.b').keyup(function(){
  var textValue1 =$(this).parent().find('.a').val();
  var textValue2 = $(this).parent().find('.b').val();

  $(this).parent().find('.price').val(textValue1 * textValue2); 

});
```

**UPDATED**

I use append to generate new row and it still didnt work not sure how can I do

```
var i = 0;
var id_i = 1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add-form').click(function() {
            i++;
            id_i++;                     
            $('#add-me').append(
                '<tbody id="row'+i+'"><tr>'+
                +'<td>'
                +'</td>'
                +'<td class="col-md-1">'
                +'<input type="text"  name="quantity_box[0]" class="form-control a" />'
                +'</td>'
                +'<td class="col-md-1">'
                +'<input type="text"  name="unit_price[]" class="form-control b" />'
                +'</td>'
                +'<td class="col-md-1">'
                +'<input type="text" name="price[0]" id="price" class="form-control price" autofocus="" />'
                +'</td>'    
                +'</tr></tbody>'
            );
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are not going up high enough. For each `.a` and `.b` element, the parent is the respective `td` - looking inside that for the corresponding other b/a element of course finds nothing, because that is not in that td. Use `parents('tr')` instead.

Comment: You should go through the jQuery documentation and learn all the ways to traverse the DOM tree.

Comment: thank you for advice I will go for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a  minor change in the code as suggested by @A. lglesias

```
  $('.a,.b').keyup(function() {

      var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
      // reason to put 1 is because if one text has value 9 and other is empty than the ouput will be 0
      var textValue1 = $row.find('input.a').val() == "" ? 1 : 
      $row.find('input.a').val();
      var textValue2 = $row.find('input.b').val() == "" ? 1 : 
       $row.find('input.b').val();

       $row.find('input.price').val(textValue1*textValue2); 

  });
```

Comment: This is work pretty good in 1st tbody but second tbody It didnt work , not sure maybe I've 2 tbody ?

Comment: working for me... checkout http://jsbin.com/naweciheci/edit?html,js,output

Comment: well thank i think I shld look in my HTML something should be wrong lol

Comment: no worries.. as long as you have both the approaches from mine and @A. Iglesias....

Comment: I updated my question your both code is work fine  but after I use append for genrate new row It wont work could you help me pls

Comment: @test1321 Use `$("body").on("keyup", ".a, .b", function(){....})` instead of `$('.a,.b').keyup....` to get the events generated by dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reach the `tr`...

```
$('table').on('keyup','input.a,input.b',function() {

    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var textValue1 = $row.find('input.a').val();
    var textValue2 = $row.find('input.b').val();

    $row.find('input.price').val(textValue1*textValue2); 

});
```

Other option...

```
$('table').on('keyup','input.a,input.b',function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $row.find('input.price').val($('input.a',$row).val() * $('input.b',$row).val());
});
```

Comment: shoud use ternary condition else output will be 0....

$row.find('input.a').val() == "" ? 1 : 
      $row.find('input.a').val();

Comment: Mmm... Sorry, but I disagree... In this case if one field is empty, the result must to be 0. He's calculating the total price, so if you don't have a prize or you don't have a number of items, the result has to be zero. Makes more sense to me.

Comment: Any price calculation should be A(10) + B(0) + C(0) = shoud be 10. in your case it turns out to be 0..... so in my approach we can make 0 instead of 1.

Comment: And by the way his code is doing multiplication so it should be 1 only.

Comment: @Kamal No, check the meaning of each input. Price calculation is Quantity*Unit_price.  If quantity or price is 0, the total has to be 0.

Comment: @Kamal Anyway, this is not a fight!! :) test1321 has both options, so he can decide which one fits better for his case

Comment: i agree ... we shared different approaches, rest depends on him!

Comment: I updated my question your both code is work fine  but after I use append for genrate new row It wont work could you help me pls  @A.Iglesias

Comment: @test1321 You have to use event delegation. I've updated my answer

Comment: @test1321 One question if you don't mind (just curiosity)... Any reason for creating a new `tbody` for each line?

Comment: @A.Iglesias Hones I dont know lol, I 'm new this javascript and I read it from some where in stackoverflow  maybe just to make sure that I make a new row

Comment: @test1321 Then, just leave one `tbody` that contains all the `tr`. You can put the row id in the `tr` element `<tr id="row'+i+'">`